# tf.metrics.mean_iou returning negative values?

Tags: tensorflow

Is it possible to get negative values for iou in tensorflow? I am getting negative values.

```
mIOU, conf_mat = tf.metrics.mean_iou(labels=gt_label, predictions=predict_labels, 
            num_classes=21, weights=tf.stack([0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]))
```

I am masking out label 0 due to it is being background label and not evaluated. But it is computed in the loss function.

Answer (score 0):

No it is not possible to get the negative values judging from the description of what it caclulates:

> IOU = true_positive / (true_positive + false_positive +
>   false_negative). The predictions are accumulated in a confusion
>   matrix, weighted by weights, and mIOU is then calculated from it.

It is hard to tell why do you get it without the data, because it looks like you use it correctly.

Comment: My predict labels are within [0-20] and the ground truth labels are in the same interval as well. However, in the confusion matrix, I notice large negative numbers. How is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

The given weights correspond each to a value pair in the prediction/gt vectors. The weights do not apply to a class index.

To exclude a class from the miou computation you could create weights as follows:

```
weights = tf.cast(tf.not_equal(gt_label, 0), tf.int32)
```

This snippet weighs the label 0 with 0 and all other labels with 1.